# How can I let a Docker image run inside a container, so it awaits for commands?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, backend

I have a problem with my Docker Container.
My backend image stops running after it has finished installing dependencies.
While my app is running there will be some querys to the backend, but because it is stopped this doesn't work.

[My Dockerfile for the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDkeE.png)

Is there a command I need to add so it runs in the background and listens for querys?

I tried using node as a base image but than it doesnt know R.

Comment: 1. Why do you need line 22 for? You already copied everything in your current directory to `/app`. 2. Your entrypoint just runs `tail`. I don't really know what R is, but it's not `tail` that's for sure..

Comment: You need something that keeps your container alive. After tail is executed the container exits. This is normal. That image says only its for R users. Sounds weird. If you give more details, maybe its possible to help you.

Comment: You don't seem to have actually included any of your application code in the question, just a link to an image file.  What is the container doing, why does it exit rather than serving requests?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?